# No module named 'Crypto'

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run this code, `from firebase import firebase`, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

I have tried the following:

```
pip install cryptop
pip3 install crypto
pip install pycryptodome
pip install pycryptodomex
```

The terminal results show:

```
Requirement already satisfied
```

When I tried the following:

```
pip install pycrypto
pip3 install pycrypto 
pip3 install --upgrade pycrypto
```

The terminal results show an error:

`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:`

I am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: There are problems with the interpreter, for help go [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Answer (score 1):

u can use; pip install cryptography,

Comment: when i run it, i get this result "Requirement already satisfied"

Answer (score 0):

The terminal is saying this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto' because you imported crypto but when you called it out in your code, it was called out with a capital c “C” when it should be lowercase.

Comment: sorry what do you mean?

Comment: You had imported crypto correctly but the program says that you commanded it out with a capital “C” not a lowercase. Please check you code and make it a lowercase c.

Comment: If you can show me your code, i’ll show you where its going wrong.

Comment: See vs code is giving you this error, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'. Notice how it has a capital c , when it shouldn't. This means that you wrote crypto with a capital c in your code when it should be in lowercase.